# How to get the version number from a DACPAC file

Tags: versioning, dacpac

I generate DACPAC files from automated builds with a generated version number.  While useful during sqlpackager operations I need to be able to determine the version number of a DACPAC before doing anything with the file.

What tooling can I use (automated of course) to query the DACPAC file for its version number and description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DACPAC files are actually zip files.  Extract the zip and query the file DacMetaData which is a xml file.  Use the XPath:  /DacType/Version

Answer (score 5):

Hey I know you found a solution but I have an alternative method that may help someone else.
By referencing Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.dll and using the [DacType](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.dac.dactype%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) class:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac;
```

(Not entirely sure which using statements are needed - I have copied for a larger DAC helper file)

```
using (Stream dacPackFileStream = File.Open(this.dacPackFileName, FileMode.Open))
{
     var dacType = DacType.Load(dacPackFileStream);
     dacPackFileStream.Close();
     return dacType.Version;
}
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner than a xml query.   Could you add where to acquire these assemblies from?  Nuget perhaps?